# How to find SSH server's public key (not key fingerprint)

Tags: linux, key-authentication

I am looking for the server's RSA public key string. I do not have permission to go to `/etc/ssh` and further so I can't read the actual public key.

I do not have access to any packet sniffing tools like WireShark.

Having these limitations, is it possible somehow to get the server's public key string?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am not interested in the fingerprint, I can get it. My question is about the actual key. So the fingerprint looks like 66:4e:67:<and so on> and the key is a straight string i.e. "A678B43234234"

Answer (score 3):

Use `ssh`'s verbose options:  `ssh -v user@hostname.example.com`, and look at stderr.

Comment: is there a way to do it from Putty or WinSCP from Windows environment?

Comment: If the server does not have a public key, the connection will be rejected? Probably password auth will be used.